# Object scaling/rotation/translation linked when no parent/child relationship exists?

Tags: modeling, origin, proportional-editing

I have a bit of a strange issue that I haven't seen with my modelling up to this point. Basically I have found some objects in my project are linked somehow. Basically they are behaving as if they have a parent child relationship when scaling/rotating/translating (I have double checked that there is no such relationship by clicking *Parent/Clear Parent* on both objects).

[image]

It seems like this happens for any pair of objects that share the same origin point? Just wondering how I can turn this off?

Comment: From your gif, looks like you have proportional editing turn it on, or it could be a constraint (Child Of)

Answer (score 0):

As [Emir](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/66870/emir) pointed out in the comments (and I just noticed myself), the issue is proportional editing being turned on.

Seems like if you have objects that share an origin (but no child/parent relationship and no other constraints), proportional editing will apply to transformations made in object mode (in addition to transformations made in edit mode on a particular object).